# Grep ignore array of patterns

Tags: grep

Since I learned some bash syntax, I have being very enthusiastic about its use in daily life. A famous command is `grep`. In case one with to grep something but ignore several files, the commands below MAY work.

```
grep_ignore=("token_a", "token_b")
grep -rnw . -e "token2" | grep -v <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]}")
```

How to reproduce:

1. Create some dummy folder: command run `mkdir dummy & cd dummy`
2. Create files:

   a. `file_token_a.txt`: command run `echo "token1 token2" > file_token_a.txt`;

   b. `file_token_b.txt`: command run `echo "token1 token3" > file_token_b.txt`

   c. `file_token_c.txt`: command run `echo "token2 token3" > file_token_c.txt`

Command run:

```
grep_ignore=("token_a", "token_b")
grep -rnw . -e "token2" | grep -v <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]}")
```

Expected output:

```
./file_token_c.txt:1:token2 token3
```

Given output:

```
./file_token_c.txt:1:token2 token3
./file_token_a.txt:1:token1 token2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues with your attempt:

1. your array construction has an erroneous comma, which makes the first pattern `token_a,` instead of `token_a`
2. `<(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]}")` is being passed to `grep -v` as <strike>a file to be searched</strike> a pattern consisting of the process substitution's file descriptor string like `/dev/fd/63`<sup>1</sup>, rather than as a list of patterns - to have patterns read from a file (or process substitution) you need to make it an argument to the `-f` option

Correcting for these:

```
grep_ignore=("token_a" "token_b")
```

then

```
$ grep -rnw . -e "token2" | grep -vFf <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]}")
./file_token_c.txt:1:token2 token3
```

(the `-F` says to treat the array elements as fixed strings rather than regular expressions).

---

Alternatively, at least in GNU grep, you can use `--exclude` (and `--include`) to limit the match to specific file subsets to avoid the second grep altogether. So using your example above:

```
$ grep -rnw . -e "token2"
./file_token_a.txt:1:token1 token2
./file_token_c.txt:1:token2 token3
```

but given an array of filename *patterns* (note the elements are separated by whitespace not commas):

```
grep_ignore=("*token_a*" "*token_b*")
```

then

```
$ grep -rnw . -e "token2" "${grep_ignore[@]/#/--exclude=}"
./file_token_c.txt:1:token2 token3
```

where the array *parameter expansion* `${grep_ignore/#/--exclude=}` expands as follows:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]/#/--exclude=}"
--exclude=*token_a*
--exclude=*token_b*
```

Alternatively you could use a *brace expansion* instead of an array:

```
grep -rnw . -e "token2" --exclude={"*token_a*","*token_b*"}
```

---

1. try it with `set -x` for example:

   ```
    $ grep -rnw . -e "token2" | grep -v <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]}")
    + grep --color=auto -rnw . -e token2
    + grep --color=auto -v /dev/fd/63
    ++ printf '%s\n'
    ./file_token_a.txt:1:token1 token2
    ./file_token_c.txt:1:token2 token3
   ```

   Note how the grep command has become `grep --color=auto -v /dev/fd/63`? You can further confirm that it's treating `/dev/fd/63` as a pattern rather than a pseudo-file as follows:

   ```
    printf '%s\n' /dev/fd/{61..65} | 
      grep -v <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignore[@]}")
   ```

   (you'll see that `/dev/fd/63` gets filtered out).

Comment: Very nice, sir! :-)

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto you're welcome - I just added a note about brace expansion (which you may find more intuitive than the array expansion)

Comment: I found this documentation for brace expansion: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Comment: @Bruno , then  consider upvoting the answer, I just did

Comment: Where is the answer you provide? I cannot see it

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto I realized your original approach would work - with a couple of corrections. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: I am very annoyed with close-enough-solutions, although most of mine are of these kinds. ;-P

Comment: You divide the answer into 3 blocks. Block 3 assumes I know what "set -x" as well as does not provide the expected output. There are still answer improvement opportunities.

Comment: @steeldriver you can use project root "https://github.com/quivero/prego" to test the commands below. The array values are not filtered out. :-(

`grep_ignores=( "*node_modules*" "*.git*" "*package-lock*" "*codecov*" "*scripts*" )`
`grep -rnw . -e "@babel/cli" | grep -vFf <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignores[@]}")`

Comment: Some holy enlightment made me change `grep -vFf` to `grep -vEf`. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -rnw token2 *.txt | grep -E -v "(token_a|token_b)"
```

seems to me to be a simpler approach, than to handle arrays.

Grep with -E for extended regular expressions, so you can use the OR-Operator "(token_a|token_b)".

Comment: The answer is a great start! We can go from it to expansions `{}`. Thanks!